# Speed problem using an R-pi to run python-whiteboard and xournal as a home-built smartboard

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I've built my own version of a smartboard for my classroom, but I'd like to migrate it to a raspberry pi. It's been running under Lubuntu on an old salvaged PC.

[Python-whiteboard](https://github.com/pnegre/python-whiteboard/wiki) uses a bluetooth-connected wii remote and an IR LED source to act as a mouse. I use [xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) because it's a pretty simple program for note-taking on tablets. I just save the day's work as a pdf, and xournal makes it simple to annotate.

[Here's a YouTube video of my earliest version.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOZ8giiWYSc)

Everything works with the Raspian (Wheezy) version except the drawing is so slow. I move the wand, and the screen takes seconds to show it. I'm pretty sure it isn't xournal, because I tried it out with Tux Draw with the same result.

Comment: very nice video. I am not sure how much CPU and memory are needed but have you tried over clocking your Pi?

Comment: @Phil Vallone - I've overclocked as much as I can without overvolting, but the lag is so great that a 10 or 25% increase would still be completely unacceptable. Overclocking any more seemed not worth the risk.

Answer (score 1):

The pi might not be powerful enough to do all the processing. I hate to admit this, but in my opinion sometimes the Pi might not be the right choice for a project that requires a lot of processing. Have you looked at any alternatives?

The following alternative will run on linux and have a lot more processing power and may be a better platform for your project:

[UDOO](http://www.udoo.org) - $99 - $135 US

Comment: The Intel Galileo is considerably slower than the Raspberry Pi; it's equivalent to a (roughly) 1st generation Pentium at 400 MHz, with a very basic maths coprocessor. Every test I've run on a Galileo vs Raspberry Pi has the Intel board coming out much slower.